# Ratio of triangle's areas

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle and let D and E be points on the sides AB and AC respectively. Prove that if

${\vert AD\vert \over \vert AB\vert}=r$ $\\$ and $\\$ ${\vert AE\vert \over \vert AC\vert}=s$

then

${Area\ \bigtriangleup ADE \over Area\ \bigtriangleup ABC}=rs$

Comment: What have you attempted ? There is a very simple proof by comparison of the norms of cross products $\vec{AD}\times\vec{AE}$ and $\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}$, but have you already seen cross products ?

Comment: Another way to prove it would be the trigonometric formula for the area of triangles: If $\alpha$ denotes the angle at the point A, then $Area_{ABC} = |AB| \cdot |AC| \cdot sin(\alpha)$ and $Area_{ADE} = |AD| \cdot |AE| \cdot sin(\alpha)$

Comment: Trivially equivalent to Ceva's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\overline{AB}$ the base of $\triangle ABC$.  By dropping perpendiculars from $C$ and $E$ to $\overline{AB}$, and examining the similar triangles thus created from vertex $A$, we see that the altitude of $\triangle ABE$ is smaller than the altitude of $\triangle ABC$ by a factor of $s$, so the area of $\triangle ABE$ is also smaller than the area of $\triangle ABC$ by a factor of $s$.

Similarly, the base $AD$ is smaller than the base $AB$ by a factor of $r$, so the area of $\triangle ADE$ is also smaller than the area of $\triangle ABE$ by a factor of $r$.

Putting these together, we find that the area of $\triangle ADE$ is smaller than the area of $\triangle ABC$ by a factor of $rs$.

Answer (score 0):

The area of triangle ABC is half the norm of $\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}.$

The area of triangle ADE is half the norm of $\vec{AD}\times\vec{AE}=r\vec{AB}\times s\vec{AC}=rs \vec{AB}\times \vec{AC}$.

Thus the area of triangle ADE is $rs$ times the area of triangle ABC.